# Differential equation with five potential solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am entirely new to Differential Equations and am stuck with the following:

$(y')^2=|4y|$

$y(1)=4$

Which of the following are solutions to the problem?

a. $y=(x+1)^2$

b. $y=(3-x)^2$

c. $y=(x+1)·|x+1|$

d. $y=0$

e. $y=(3-x)·|3-x|$

I would say all of them, except for d. However, I am not sure, and c. and e. in particular are throwing me off, and I am not sure how to approach them. Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to plug the solutions in the equation ?

Comment: Yes, but with c. and e. I am not 100% sure how to do it because of the absolute sign.

Comment: The derivative of $|x|$ is $1$ if $x>0$, $-1$ if $x<0$.

Answer (score 3):

All solutions except d) are of the form

$$y=\pm(x-a)^2$$ where the sign only depends on the sign of $x-a$.

But in all cases

$$(y')^2=(\pm2(x-a))^2=4(x-a)^2=4|y|.$$

We also have

$$(0')^2=4|0|.$$

Remains to check the initial condition.